# UI Router - How to ensure templateUrl reloads for every call

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using angular js 1.6 and ui-router. I have a requirement where I need to refresh the ui-view everytime I click a link

```
$stateProvider.state({
    name : 'taskDetails',
    templateUrl : '/test/associateTask.htm'
})
```

How can I achieve it using ui-router. What I found is associateTask.html is called as a GET request and called only once.

Answer (score 0):

I use this; stole it somewhere from StackOverflow. Basically what it does is put the reload option when it's not specified.

```
crmApp.config(function ($provide) {
  $provide.decorator('$state', function ($delegate) {
    var state = $delegate;

    state.baseGo = state.go;

    var go = function (to, params, options) {
      options = options || {};

      if (angular.isUndefined(options.reload)) {

          options.reload = true;
      }

      this.baseGo(to, params, options);
    };

    state.go = go;

    return $delegate;
  });
})
```